# In a set of numbers, how to find all the sums that total a certain number?

Tags: summation

This is not really a Mathematica question, its more a programming question but Mathematica usually has some clever way to do things.

Suppose I have a set of numbers. How can I obtain all the sums that yield a certain $x$ with these numbers? For example: $A=\{3_1,4,6_1,7,6_2,9,3_2\}$ and want to know how many sums yield seven. Then we have:

$$7=7 \\ 3_1+4=7 \\ 4+3_2=7$$

I tried to do but what I did was so ugly I deleted it. There were a lot of loops and a huge code for something I believe that can be done with much less code. My other trial involved something a little bit uncomputable: Taking the powerset of $A$ and passing a loop with `Total[]` on each element of $P(A)$.

Comment: `IntegerPartitions[7, Length[a], a]`?

Comment: @Kuba This would work for the problem I posed, thanks. But do you know  how could I do it for a set like: $\{\{1,"a"\},\{2,"b"\}\}$ comparing only via the first element?

Comment: `a=list[[All, 1]]`

Comment: Do you wish to enumerate the sums or do you simply "want to know how many sums yield seven?"

Comment: Maybe: `In[275]:= vals = {3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 9, 3};
vars = Array[x, Length[vals]];
Solve[Flatten[{vars.vals == 7, 
   Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, vars]}], vars, Integers]

Out[277]= {{x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 1, x[5] -> 0, 
  x[6] -> 0, x[7] -> 0}, {x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 1, x[3] -> 0, x[4] -> 0, 
  x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> 0, x[7] -> 1}, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 1, x[3] -> 0, 
  x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, x[6] -> 0, x[7] -> 0}}`

Answer (score 3):

You can get the values this way:

```
vals = {3, 4, 6, 7, 6, 9, 3};
sub = Subsets[vals, {2}];
sums = sub[[#, 1]] + sub[[#, 2]] & /@ Range[Length[sub]];
Join[Flatten[sub[[#]] & /@ Position[sums, 7], 1], Cases[vals, 7]]
```

> {{3,4},{4,3},7}